# Condition for negative semidefiniteness of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices

Suppose I have matrices $A, B, D \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, where $D$ is symmetric and positive semidefinite. Furthermore, let $\alpha_1 \in [0,1], \alpha_2 \in [0,2]$ be known scalars. Is there any condition I could put on $A$ and $B$ to ensure the following?

\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha_1 D & - \alpha_1 D \\
-\alpha_1 D &   \alpha_2 D
\end{bmatrix} - 
\begin{bmatrix}
A &  0 \\
0 &   B
\end{bmatrix}^T
\begin{bmatrix}
D &  D \\
D &  D
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
A &  0 \\
0 &   B
\end{bmatrix} \leq 0
\end{equation}

I tried to explore the Schur complement which works quite fine for the positive semidefinite counterparts, but for negative semidefiniteness, it seems to be quite hard.

Comment: Where does that problem come from. Seems to me like an XY-problem. https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: *"where is symmetric and positive semidefinite"*???

Comment: some lecture exercises (not particularly motivated I believe)

Answer (score 2):

You could write this in the form $P - Q^TDQ \leq 0$, where
$$
P = \begin{bmatrix}
\alpha_1 D & - \alpha_1 D \\
-\alpha_1 D &   \alpha_2 D
\end{bmatrix}, \quad Q =\begin{bmatrix}
 A & B
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
If $D$ is known to be invertible, then this is the Schur complement of $D^{-1}$ within the matrix
$$
M = \begin{bmatrix}
D^{-1} & Q\\
Q^T & P
\end{bmatrix} = 
 \begin{bmatrix}
D^{-1} & A & B\\
A^T & \alpha_1 D & -\alpha_1 D\\
B^T & -\alpha_1 D & \alpha_2 D
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Thus, your condition is equivalent to $M$ having $n$ positive eigenvalues and $2n$ non-positive eigenvalues.

Note that the block-matrix $P$ can be written as the Kronecker product
$$
P = \begin{bmatrix}
\alpha_1 & -\alpha_1\\
-\alpha_1 & \alpha_2
\end{bmatrix}\otimes D.
$$
As such, we can see that $P$ will have the maximal possible number of non-negative eigenvalues (excluding the case where $\alpha_1 = \alpha_2 = 0$) when $\alpha_1 \alpha_2 - \alpha_1^2 \leq 0 \implies \alpha_2 \leq \alpha_1$; the original condition cannot hold otherwise.  In this case, and if $P$ is inveritble, $M$ will satisfy the desired condition if and only if the Schur complement of $P$ is negative definite.

Putting it all together, we can say that if $D$ is invertible and $\alpha_2 < \alpha_1$, then your condition is equivalent to
$$
D^{-1} - QPQ^T \leq 0\implies\\
D^{-1} - \alpha_1(ADA^T) + \alpha_1(ADB^T + BDA^T) - \alpha_2 BDB^T \leq 0.
$$

Comment: Thank you so much Ben! $\alpha_2 \geq \alpha_1$, but I can shuffle terms around to guarantee that  $\alpha_2=\alpha_1$.

Comment: @Taiwaninja Interesting. It is worth noting that if $\alpha_2 > \alpha_1$ and $D$ is invertible, then your condition **cannot** hold by [the Cauchy interlacing theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Cauchy_interlacing_theorem).

Comment: Thank you @Ben_Grossman! This is great info! I was not aware of the existence of the Cauchy interlacing theorem. Will take a deeper look into it :)